# How to sort array based on another arrays position?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have a `tableView` with its style being `Right Detail`. I therefore have 2 `arrays`, one is for the `textLabels` data, and the other is for `detailTextLabel`.

There will be 2 "sort by" options. One will be sort by the `textLabels` data, and the second will sort by the `detailTextlabels` data. So when I sort the first `array` (`textLabels array`), the second `array (detailTextLables` array`) will also have to get sorted based on the first`array`.

I know how to sort `arrays`, but how can I sort one `array` based on another?

Here's how I sorted the `array`: (it's an `array` of `Dates`.

```
firstArray.sort({ (a, b) -> Bool in
    a.earlierDate(b) == a
})
```

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? Please include relevant code snippets. See [ask]

Comment: And, FWIW, I would recommend not having 2 separate arrays, but having 1 array with objects in it that have multiple fields.

Comment: Do you mean a dictionary?

Comment: No, probably something like `struct Item { let text, detailText: String }`

Comment: Or even `[(text: String, detailText: String)]`. Having two arrays is a mistake.

Comment: Can someone explain why having 2 `arrays` is wrong. And my original question still stays if I have a nested array, or dictionary, (I think.)

Comment: It's a question of architecture/design. Logically it makes sense to group these things together — they probably represent some real-world "object" with multiple attributes. Furthermore once you group them into one type, it automatically becomes impossible for the arrays to get out of sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit messy, but you can use `enumerate` to work with indices and elements at the same time:

```
array1.enumerate().sort {
    return $0.element < $1.element
}.map {$0.element}

array1.enumerate().sort {
    return array2[$0.index] < array2[$1.index]
}.map {$0.element}
```

But it's really much simpler/easier with one array.

```
struct Item {
    let prop1: Int
    let prop2: String
}

var array = [
    Item(prop1: 1, prop2: "c"),
    Item(prop1: 2, prop2: "b"),
    Item(prop1: 3, prop2: "a")
]

array.sort { $0.prop1 < $1.prop1 }

array.sort { $0.prop2 < $1.prop2 }
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in swift, and never worked with structs. How would I add items to this kind of `array`?

Comment: Added an example. I would recommend reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer**s**!! I tried this, and at the line of `sort`, I get the following error: Cannot invoke 'sort' with an argument list of type '((_, _) -> _)'

Answer (score 3):

First, why not have two arrays? Because you only have one array of UITableViewCells and you want to keep all the data associated with a particular table view cell together. And it makes the need to try to coordinate the sorting of multiple arrays (what you are asking to do) unnecessary.

But if you really want to do that:

```
var array1 = ["1", "3", "2"]
var array2 = ["One", "Three", "Two"]

let sortedFoo = zip(array1, array2).sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }

array1 = sortedFoo.map { $0.0 }
array2 = sortedFoo.map { $0.1 }
```

The idea with the above code is that it combines the two arrays into one array of tuples, and then sorts them based on the elements in the first array, then breaks that single array back out into two separate arrays.

In other words, since you have to combine the two arrays into one to do the sort anyway, you might as well make them in a single array in the first place. :-)

Answer (score 2):

How about using using `positionOf` on the sorted array to find the corresponding index in the I sorted array?

Comment: definitely the solution.