# How can I sort an array of Strings by another array of Ints in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm using this code in the Playground as an example:

```
let videosUnsorted = ["C Video", "G Video", "L Video", "T Video", "S Video ", "P Video", "A Video", "Z Video", "R Video"]

let videosValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

let sorted = videosUnsorted.sorted(by: {$0.videosValues > $1.videosValues})
print(sorted)
```

but it's giving me this error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

I tried the following but it's not what I'm trying to accomplish. It's only sorting by the elements in the same array:

```
let sorted = videosUnsorted.sorted(by: {$0.1 < $1.2})
```

Comment: $0 is a `String`, and it doesn't have a property `videosValues`.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589534/1630618)

Comment: What result do you expect after the sort is complete? Please [edit] your question (no comments) with the exact results you want.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `zip()` like this:

`zip(videosUnsorted, videosValues).sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 }).map { $0.0 }`

This combines the 2 arrays into the type `[(String, Int)]` you then sort by the `Int` values and use `map()` to get back out just the sorted `[String]`.